# Firestore: REST API runQuery method expects wrong parent path pattern

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to perform a simple query with Firestore REST API.

Being on Google App Engine standard I cannot use the google-cloud-firestore client which is not yet compatible with GAE standard. Instead, I'm using google-api-python-client as for other Google APIs.

This is how I initialize my service:

```
service = build('firestore', 'v1beta1', credentials=_credentials)
```

Once this is done, I perform the query that way:

```
query = { "structuredQuery":
          {
            "from": [{ "collectionId": "mycollection" }],
            "where": {
              "fieldFilter":
              {
                "field": { "fieldPath": "myfield" },
                "op": "EQUAL",
                "value": { "stringValue": "myvalue" }
              }
            }
          }
        }

response = service.projects().databases().documents().runQuery(
            parent='projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents',
            body=query).execute()
```

This returns an error quite explicit:

> TypeError: Parameter "parent" value
>   "projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents"
>   does not match the pattern
>   "^projects/[^/]+/databases/[^/]+/documents/[^/]+/.+$"

which obviously is true. My point is that the documentation cleary states that this should be an accepted value:

> The parent resource name. In the format: `projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents` or `projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}`. For example: `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents` or `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents/chatrooms/my-chatroom` (string)

Performing the same query with the API Explorer (or curl) works fine and **returns the expected results**. (even though the API Explorer does state that the parent parameter does not match the expected pattern).

[image: API Explorer pattern not matching]

It seems that the discovery document (which is used by google-api-python-client) enforces this pattern check for the parent parameter but the associated regular expression does not actually allow the only parent path that seems to work (projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents).

I tried to use a different pattern path like `projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents/*/**`, which makes the query run fine but does not return any results.

Is anyone having the same issue or am I doing something wrong here ?
The only workaround I can think of is making a request directly to the proper url without using google-api-python-client, but that means that I have to handle the auth process manually which is a pain.

Thanks for any help you could provide !

Comment: Did you find to any solution to this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Well I just implemented the call manually for this particular method. What I do is build the service like you normally do with google-api-python-client, then use the auth token from the service to make a request with urlfetch (or requests), passing the token in the headers. You also need to refresh the token if it has expired.

Comment: Same here, but the API Explorer did not work

Answer (score 0):

`google-cloud-firestore` is now compatible with standard App Engine.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers

Answer (score 0):

for your information, a trick works.
You can change the uri after generating the request :

```
request = service.projects().databases().documents().runQuery(
            parent='projects/myprojectid/databases/(default)/documents/*/**',
            body=query)
request.uri = request.uri.replace('/*/**', '')

response = request.execute()
```